# Prove that f is not differentiable at x=0

Tags: limits, derivatives

Question:

For $x$ $\in \mathbb{R}$ , prove that $f(x) = \lim_{n\to \infty}(x+\sqrt{1/n})$ is not differntiable for $x=0$.

My attempt (which my results contradicts the question):

$f(x) = \lim_{n\to \infty}(x+\sqrt{1/n})=2x$ which is differentiable $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$. And so $f$ is infact differentiable at $x=0$.

I am convinced there must be a mistake in computing $f$ (line 2)?

Comment: You completely changed the problem with your edit.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, i.e. $=x$ if $x\geq0$ and $=-x$ if $x<0$. So your function in question is actually:
$$ f(x) = \lim_{n\to \infty}\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+1/n}\right)=x+|x|$$
which is not differentiable at $0$

Answer (score 0):

Actually,$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+\frac1n}\right)=x+\sqrt{x^2}=x+|x|,$$which is not differentiable at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=x+|x|$;

1) $x <0$;

$\dfrac{x+|x|}{x}=1-1=0$;

2) $x>0$;

$\dfrac{x+|x|}{x}=1+1=2$;

Hence?